# Self Uninstall of application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uninstallation

is there possibility to do uninstall of your application which runs under iPhone?
There could be a number of cases when you want application to uninstall itself.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you are considering some additional copy protection? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't uninstall your own application from code, period. Or any other application for that matter. Uninstall is always an action initiated by the user. I would imagine it being possible for jailbroken iPhones though, but that would make use of not supported/forbidden APIs & commands.